# What builds the twitter and facebook tables for allauth?

Tags: django, authentication

I installed the https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth package via pip. I followed the README.rst and after a bit of rigmarole got almost everything to work.

The facebook, twitter, openid and emailconfirmation sections are now appearing in my admin screen, but when I click on any of their menu items I get an error such as:

```
no such table: twitter_twitterapp
```

and a similar error for each of the four new apps. Did I miss a step or some steps in the installation process where the database tables get created?

I'm using sqlite3, if that has any bearing on the isssue.

Comment: sycndb! but I saw mention of that while installing django_social_auth having given up on allauth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not already done `syncdb` then you must do that once. After doing that go in your admin and you will see a section for twitterapp and another for facebookapp. There you need to add the required keys.